# horizontal scrolling Images like on Netflix

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, scroll

i'm trying to create a website with video content and i want to have a horizontal selection of cover pictures on the main page, like netflix does.

Which means lots of pictures which spread over the screen size and will scroll via mouseover arrows on the right / left side of the screen.

Screenshot:

http://cdn3-i.hitc-s.com/180/netflix_redesign_70590.jpg

Does anyone know how to create that?
I'm using Dreamweaver and Muse, got some basic html and css skills, used a bit of jquery code, but i'm not quite firm with it yet.

Bye, Robert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have much experience then I would recommend you use a plugin such as [Owl Carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/owlcarousel).

It can do pretty much everything that you want out of the box.

There are plenty of other options out there but this one does have touch support and is responsive as well so it's pretty good.

This [blog post](http://designscrazed.org/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/) lists out lots of them (including Owl Carousel).
You will probably get lots of others recommended by other users too.

When do you do have time I would also recommend trying to write your own carousel. It may seem like a waste of time with so many options out there but it really is a good way of enhancing your html, css and javascript.

Carousels are of my favourite example projects to help train junior developers at work.

Answer (score 15):

**Start with some basic CSS styling:**

This will cover the basic look and feel of Netflix:

```
body {
    background: #141414;
}
#hold_images {
    display: inline-block; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#icon_right {
    right: 20; 
    cursor: pointer;  
    margin-top: -200px; 
    position: fixed; 
}
#icon_left {
    left: 20; 
    cursor: pointer;  
    margin-top: -200px; 
    position: fixed; 
}
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
img {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

**Add a div to your body to hold the images:**

```
<body>

<div id='hold_images'></div>

</body>
```

**Use jQuery to handle the image and icon appending, image hovering, and smooth scrolling:**

The images are captured screenshots saved to an img folder, and a library was used for adding the chevron icons but you can use whatever.

```
images = {
   "1" : "img/1.png",
   "2" : "img/2.png",
   "3" : "img/3.png",
   "4" : "img/4.png",
   "5" : "img/5.png",
   "6" : "img/6.png",
   "7" : "img/7.png",
   "8" : "img/8.png",
   "9" : "img/9.png",
   "10" : "img/10.png"
}

Object.keys(images).forEach(function(path) {
    $('#hold_images').append("<img class='my_img' width=200 height=400 src=" + images[path] + ">"); 
});

$('body').append("<i id='icon_right'></i>");
$('body').append("<i id='icon_left'></i>"); 
add_icon('#icon_right', 'fa fa-chevron-right', '40px', 'white');
add_icon('#icon_left', 'fa fa-chevron-left', '40px', 'white');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_img').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');
    
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#icon_right, #icon_left', function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'icon_right') {
        $('body').animate({scrollLeft: 1000}, 800);
        } else {
        $('body').animate({scrollLeft: -1000}, 800);
    }
});
```

**Result:**

[image]

**NOTE**: You don’t need the ‘add_icon’ function above. You can simply add your own buttons or icons for the left and right events.

Comment: where is the documentation for that `add_icon(..)` function?

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel you don't need to implement the add_icon function.  Remove it from above code and manually code in your style settings for the left / right arrows.  I had to modify the above code a bit to get it working for my use case.  It's a great starting point for anyone that needs a little push in the right direction....  nice answer.